# "Some mandatory parameters are missing" After minor upgrade withing symfony 5.4LTS

Tags: routes, optional-parameters, symfony5

Since the last update of symfony 5.4 LTS (subv 15 I believe) there has been some change in optional routing parameters... this previously worked:

template

```
{{ path('app_support_case_new') }}
```

controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/{type}", name="app_support_case_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new($type=null, Request $request, SupportCaseRepository $supportCaseRepository, SupportTypeRepository $supportTypeRepository, globalHelper $helper, MailerInterface $mailer): Response
{
```

The error is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some
> mandatory parameters are missing ("type") to generate a URL for route
> "app_support_case_new".").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional parameters must now be at the end in the controller argument list

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/{type}", name="app_support_case_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request, SupportCaseRepository $supportCaseRepository, SupportTypeRepository $supportTypeRepository, globalHelper $helper, MailerInterface $mailer, $type=null): Response
{
```